# Netbeans doesn't suggestion methods when I have several files

Tags: php, netbeans

I have a php project with several files in netbeans. Lets say in one file looks like this:

```
<?php
$foo = new Foo();

?>
```

When I type `$foo->` in this file Netbeans suggests all the methods and properties.
When I start typing `$foo->` in a different file Netbeans suggests that I mean `$foo`, so fare so good.
But then Netbeans has forgotten about the type and doesn't suggest any methods.

Also `/* @var $foo Foo */` does not help.

Is it possible to tell netbeans that `$foo` is always a object of the Class Foo?

Comment: Have you correctly configured the `include_path` in your Netbeans project? Can the file containing the class `Foo` be found in the include path? Are you including/requiring the file where needed or is the class loaded dynamically with autoload?

Comment: If haven't configured the include_path. Do I have to, when I need no external source code? The Class is defines in a different file (part of the same project) and all these files are included by one file, first the class definition, then the file I quoted above and then the other files.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's a way to. You should file this as a bug: http://netbeans.org/community/issues.html